# Windows 7.1 Emulator not able to connect server running on Host / VM machine

Tags: windows-phone-7.1.1, windows-phone-7-emulator

I am using Windows Phone 7.1 emulator to connect to TCP server hosted on local machine or VM system on the host machine.

The emulator is not able to connect to the host TCP service.

I tried with IPv4, localhost.

Thanks
Sandy

Comment: Define "not able to connect". What happens when you try? How are you trying to connect - in an app or through the browser?

Comment: @Matt
I am trying to connect Phone Emulator Client socket code to connect to Windows Default "Simple TCP/IP Services" i.e. Server listing on port 7 and 17.
It works well when i execute in office network but not when execute from home network. In home network different IP address gets assigned but when i am it refers to Link Local IP address.
MS Doc specifies that with 7.1 you will be able to connect using localhost which is not possible in Windows Phone 8.

Comment: @Matt I referred http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580%28v=vs.105%29.aspx